# Unable to view list of Stored Proc's

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am accessing my database using SSMS 2008 R2.

This database has been around a long time, but for some reason today I can't seem to view any of the custom stored procedures. There should be a list of ~30 in the dbo schema, but Object Explorer will only show me a list of "System Stored Procedures".

One of the DBA's just executed a CREATE SP script against the database which executed successfully... but we are unsure why I am unable to view it.

Comment: Did you log in using a different account today?  For instance using a SQL login rather than the windows one you usually use.

Comment: Yeah, it must be a permissions issue. If you can't see them through object explorer you probably won't have the permissions necessary to use the system tables, but you could try "Select * From sysobjects Where xtype = 'p'".

Comment: I used my Windows login as usual. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**First, try this in SSMS.**

```
SELECT * FROM sys.procedures order by name
```

If that works, then you probably just need to reboot.

If that doesn't work, it will probably tell you exactly why it didn't work, such as a permissions issue.

There is a very high probability that either DB permissions have changed, or your user account has changed on the network in some fashion.

Comment: I did this and it returned an empty table. What does that mean?

Comment: @SteveScott Not entirely sure as this continues working for me as of SQL Server 2016. Is it possible that you are connected to an incorrect DB server, one that has no SPs?